# Can I change CSS style after HTML load in multiple places

Tags: html, css

I have HTML code the loads a grid of images. The images have a box-shadow around them. Each image is loaded one by one on the grid, but they are all using the same style sheet. I want to make each box-shadow a different colour for the images. Is this possible?

I tried to test this a simple way by making each alternate image's shadow a different colour, but it only uses the last image's colour that is loaded for all of the images. Here is how I tested it:

```
//i is defined outside this
if($i == 0){
    //I am using PHP to print out the HTML
    Echo "<style> ul.rig li { box-shadow: 0 0 10px #2de61c; }</style>";
    $i++;
}else if($i == 1){
    Echo "<style> ul.rig li { box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ed1515; }</style>";
    $i--;
}
```

Whatever `i` equals for the last loaded image, the rest of the image's shadows will have that colour. Is it possible to alternate/have different colours like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use nth-child CSS.

```
ul.rig li:nth-child(odd) { box-shadow: 0 0 10px #2de61c; }
ul.rig li:nth-child(even) { box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ed1515; }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: That works, thanks. Though it works, the odd/even was just a simple example of what I wanted and I actually plan on changing the backgroung according to an element of the image, say, if the image's title contained "Apple", then the background would be green, that is why I was changing it in my PHP code. Is there a similar function to nth-child that could achieve something like that?

Comment: Well as Žilvinas mentioned what you're doing when you just redeclare the CSS for the same element is just overriding the resulting CSS applied to all `ul.rig li` elements, which is why they all load as the color of the last loaded one. If you want to do something more arbitrary then you'll have to do something like Ishio's answer and give the element an `apple` class and define `ul.rig li.apple { box-shadow: 0 0 10px green; }`

Answer (score 1):

Why not use something like:

```
 //i is defined outside this
 if($i == 0){
     //I am using PHP to print out the HTML
     Echo "<htmlselector class="1"></htmlselector>";
     $i++;
 }else if($i == 1){
     Echo "<htmlselector class="1x"</htmlselector>";
     $i--;
 }
```

This way you can use CSS and style them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could load images into that grid together with a certain class. Then give each of those classes a preferred style. Because what you do now is just overriding css.